# How to implement the COVAR formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, covariance, portfolio

I've been calculating the variance of two stocks and it requires the covariance to finish the calculation. But I want to use VBA to implement the formula.

**Range G4:G25** has the data of the returns of Microsoft and **Range H4:H25** has the data of the returns Apple Inc. and **Range I4:I25** has the data of the returns Facebook and **Range J4:J25** has the data of the returns Exxon.

I have named Range G4:G25 as **Range1** and Range H4:H25 as **Range2** and I4:I25 as **Range3** and J4:J25 as **Range4**

This is my code below

```
Dim data1 As Integer
Dim data2 As Integer

If ComboBox1 = "microsoft" Then data1 = Range("Range1").Select
If ComboBox1 = "facebook" Then data1 = Range("Range3").Select
If ComboBox2 = "apple" Then data2 = Range("Range2").Select
If ComboBox2 = "exxon" Then data2 = Range("Range4").Select
Range("G32").Formula = "=COVAR(Range(data1),Range(data2))"
```

I am not getting any result with this Covariance formula. I am getting the "#NAME?" error in cell G32. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't paste the formula into a range via a value, which is what your VBA code is trying to do. Instead try to use `Application.Covar` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in this way, please:

```
Sub testCovarFunction()
  Dim data1 As Range, data2 As Range

    If ComboBox1 = "microsoft" Then
        Set data1 = Range("Range1")
    ElseIf ComboBox1 = "facebook" Then
        Set data1 = Range("Range3")
    End If

    If ComboBox2 = "apple" Then
        Set data2 = Range("Range2")
    ElseIf ComboBox2 = "exxon" Then
        Set data2 = Range("Range4")
    End If
    Range("G32").Formula = "=COVAR(" & data1.Address & "," & data2.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

If you need everything in VBA, try this code, please:

```
Sub testCovarFunctionBis()
  Dim data1 As Variant, data2 As Variant

    If ComboBox1 = "microsoft" Then
        data1 = Range("Range1").value
    ElseIf ComboBox1 = "facebook" Then
        data1 = Range("Range3").value
    End If

    If ComboBox2 = "apple" Then
        data2 = Range("Range2").value
    ElseIf ComboBox2 = "exxon" Then
        data2 = Range("Range4").value
    End If
    Range("G32").value = WorksheetFunction.Covar(data1, data2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub SubCovarFormula()

    Dim data1 As Integer
    Dim data2 As Integer

    If ComboBox1 = "microsoft" Then data1 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Range1"))
    If ComboBox1 = "facebook" Then data1 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Range3"))
    If ComboBox2 = "apple" Then data2 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Range2"))
    If ComboBox2 = "exxon" Then data2 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("Range4"))

    Range("G2").Formula = "=COVAR(" & data1 & "," & data2 & ")"

End Sub
```

Tell me if it works and feel free to ask any clarification.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no `COVAR` function or formula in Excel having `Integer` as arguments... Formula needs ranges, but writing it from VBA, the range address must be supplied. The VBA function needs arrays...

Comment: Ye, your solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn on your Macro Recorder and click on the cell with any function you need to convert to VBA, and you will have all the code you need.  You will almost certainly have more code than you need, but that's a story for another day.